# Removing "www." from domain in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I've set up my server using AWS (Route53 + ElasticBeanstalk). Of course Route53 won't let me set my CNAME to the apex of the domain, so I have to put "www." in front of my domain. The domain is quite short so the www. looks bad, and I want it gone! How can I accomplish this in Node.JS or through the ElasticBeanstalk configuration? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, Route 53 won't let you set a `CNAME` at the apex of the domain, because that's not a valid DNS configuration... but that is why AWS introduced aliases... Route 53 will allow you to create an `ALIAS` at the apex of the domain, which references the Elastic Load Balancer of your elastic beanstalk deployment.

> You can use the next option if you want to associate a zone apex with your load balancer DNS name.
>
> Option 2: Create a domain using Amazon Route 53 as the DNS service. Amazon Route 53 stores information about your domain in a hosted zone. A hosted zone is an Amazon Route 53 concept that is similar to a zone file on a DNS name server. Like a zone file, a hosted zone contains information about your domain name, including the subdomain names within the domain and mappings between names and IP address ...
>
> Use this option to associate a zone apex with your load balancer DNS name. You’ll use Amazon Route 53 to create a hosted zone for your domain (for example, example.com), and then create alias resource record sets. An alias resource record set contains a pointer to a resource record set that contains your DNS resource records. For example, an alias resource record set for your domain, example.com, can point to the DNS name of your Elastic Load Balancing load balancer instance myLB-1234567890.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. After you create a hosted zone, you can also create alias resource record sets to associate subdomain names with your Elastic Load Balancing instance.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-domain-names-with-elb.html

The alias record, when queried, will return one of the IP addresses of your elastic load balancer each time it is queried.